# How to express " I had already quit this company at the end of May 2020." in Korean?

Tags: translation

I've been creating my resume in Korean and I'd like to write my experience next I'm not sure how to express below sentence in Korean.

" I had already quit this company at the end of May 2020."

I've just started learning Korean since this month.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I had already quit this company at the end of May 2020.

2020년 5월 말에 이미 퇴사하였습니다.